# Where to register IoC for class library?

Tags: architecture, inversion-of-control, layer

I have asp.net mvc web application and it is dependent on class library. I instantiate its classes by Autofac IoC.
But this class library is dependent on lower layer (yet another class library), which is not referenced in web application. And also the classes from this lowes layer I would like to instantiate by Autofac. But here is the question - where to register the classes and interfaces for autofac for this lowest layer?
Should I make in class library project referenced by web application (middle layer) some config class with one static method, in which shall I register the classes and interfaces from the lowest layer and call it in application_start of web project?
Shouldn't I register in this method the classes from both layers (middle and lowest, both class libraries)?
Or should I make a special autofac config/registration project? It seems needless to me.

Thanks for tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the option of the separate configuration project which references all other projects is valid (i've done it myself), but there's alot to be said for using [modules](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules), where each project can configure itself.
(Note that its drawback is that now all your projects have to know and reference autofac)